# How to pronounce R²

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation

How do I pronounce R² as seen in chemistry formulas or maths? I can pronounce it as "R-square" but what other word is there for "square"?

Comment: I always pronounce R2D2 the way C3PO does.

Comment: sorry c3po what? sry im no native english speaker

Comment: It’s the [Lucasian equation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=r2d2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, if 2 is above R, then it can be termed as:

> Superior character or Superscript

Or if the 2 is below R, then it can be termed as :

> Inferior character or Subscript.

Comment: The OP asked how it's pronounced, not what the technical term for it is.

Comment: @ErikKowal read his last sentence... "I can pronounce as R square but what other word for square?"

Answer (score 3):

Try *"R squared", "R raised to the power two",* or *"R to the power of two".*

Answer (score 2):

In chemistry, the number is pronounced as usual. H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> is pronounced "H two O two".

In maths, it is different. You need to know what the function of the number is. 2 can be "two", or "squared" or other names.

Comment: And **²H₂O** is pronounced *deuterium oxide*. :)

Comment: @tchrist - I should have used the formula for glucose. ;-)

Comment: It turns out that [the ratios of **H₂¹⁶O** and **H₂¹⁸O**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_isotope_ratio_cycle) are important for [measuring certain things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Δ18O). I have no idea how to say those.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, a common short form of "R to the power of two" is "R to the two" (but not "R to two"). This expression is used for general powers (x^7, 2^6, e^x, etc.), whereas for powers 2 and 3 one usually uses "squared" and "cubed".